# Tab character trimmed when reaching the end of page

Tags: html, css, indentation

I have a situation like this http://jsfiddle.net/9cRpe/ .
You can see that the &#09 chars (tab character in html) is trimmed/removed when reaching the end of page. Is it something that can be modified by css so the tab is not trimmed?
See the attached image for the result i'd like to achieve. Thanks
[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9cRpe/3/ How about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>white-space: pre-wrap;</strike>

[MDN Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/white-space)

**Edit**: OK, I made a silly answer.

I think the [Tab] character is not designed to act as "insert *n* spaces here". Instead, consider the following scenario:

> --->code
>
> //->code

You can see this in many IDE as long as you don't convert [Tab]s to [Space]s. So I think the [Tab] character means "push the next character to the next tab position".

That's why you don't see a desired space, because "the next character has already been placed in the next tab position".

Compare these two fiddles: http://jsfiddle.net/9cRpe/1/, http://jsfiddle.net/9cRpe/2/,

notice the space I added before the first "===>", and you can see the first "<===" doesn't move ---- it always aligns to the "tab" word on the first line.

I can't think of a solution right now, but I want to cover my previous stupid-ness, so I write these things that hopefully can inspire you...

Answer (score 0):

Try 5 `&nbsp;` insted of `&#09`

Comment: sorry I can't do that. It's a part of a complex application. It has to be $#09